# Strange expression for limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What do these limits $\psi(x+0), \psi(x-0)$ mean?. I did calculus but have never come across this.

Comment: $\displaystyle\psi(x+0)=\lim_{t\to x^+}\psi(t)$ and $\displaystyle\psi(x-0)=\lim_{t\to x^-}\psi(t)$

Comment: I always thought $\psi(x+0)=\psi(x)$.

Comment: If $\psi(x)$ has a jump at $x$, then the value that $\psi(t)$  approaches when $t$ is just below $x$ is different from the value that $\psi(t)$ approaches when $t$ is just above $x$.  For shorthand, we call those limits $\psi(x-0)$ and $\psi(x+0)$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These notations mean
$\displaystyle\psi(x+0)=\lim_{t\to x^+}\psi(t)$ and $\displaystyle\psi(x-0)=\lim_{t\to x^-}\psi(t)$ and these notations $\psi(x+),\psi(x^+)$ are also used for the same meaning. See [Dirichlet_conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) as an example of  use.